# Android: How to get JSONArray string in different variables

Tags: android, json, arrays

I'm building an application in which I'm consuming server side JSON data in `["anything","everthing"]` this format. I'm trying to store both strings into different different variables, I have tried these code:

```
try {
        URL API = new URL(
                "http://......com/asd.php");
        URLConnection tc = API.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                Log.i(i);
                Log.i("JSONArray String here " + ja.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting out in one single string. Can anyone help me getting these two string stored in different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    Log.i(i);
    Log.i("JSONArray String here " + ja.getString(i));
 }
//Your Code...
```

Comment: Thank You for that, now I'm getting strings in the loop. I need to store each value in different different varaibles to show it in the textview. How can I do that. Please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: no need to use more variables just use ArrayList to add all values and then use ArrayList to show values in textview

Comment: One more thing, when I'm using `ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();` and after doing all this after the loop I'm using `Log.i("Array List Item 1: " + listItems.get(0));` and `Log.i("Array List Item 2: " + listItems.get(1));`, I'm getting force close with error `IndexOutOfBound` Invalid index 0, size is 0. Any idea why am I getting this.

Comment: first thing is that declare arraylist globally. and after adding elements to ArrayList check the size of arraylist